# How to pass a state variable as a string in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, npm, syntax

I'm using the NPM package [react-date-countdown-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-countdown-timer) where I'm supposed to follow this formate to implement the countdown timer:

```
<DateCountdown dateTo='January 01, 2023 00:00:00 GMT+03:00' callback={()=>alert('Hello')}  />
```

The way I want to apply this package is by setting the property **dateTo** to a dynamic date (changes depending on an event). This dynamic date is saved into a state variable called closingTime. To implement this, in the return function of the page I do the following:

```
<DateCountdown dateTo={this.state.closingTime} callback={this.endAuction} />
```

By doing so NaN NaN NaN NaN gets displayed in the countdown timer. When I replace the state variable with its string content 'March 26, 2021 22:00:01 GMT+04:00', it operates fine.

How can I pass a state variable as a string in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your closingTime variable is a date Object. You can convert dateObject to string in javascript by using dateObject.toString() method. So you can either save a string in your state by

```
this.setState(state => {
  return { closingTime: newClosingTime.toString() }
})
```

Alternatively you can save a date object in the state and just convert it to string while passing it as a prop

```
<DateCountdown dateTo={this.state.closingTime.toString()} callback={this.endAuction} />
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! but neither methods did work.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link where I can see the code to get more details

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to String like this

```
<DateCountdown dateTo={this.state.closingTime.toString()} callback={()=>alert('Hello')}  />
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! but this method didn't work

Comment: what is the content of your ```this.state.closingTime```?

Comment: When I log it into the console, this is the content "March 26, 2021 22:00:01 GMT+04:00". EDIT: It works now! I had to change the initialization of closingTime from empty string to 0. Thank you!